# Supertest and Jest with Typescript throws "Variable 'request' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined."

Tags: typescript, jestjs, supertest

I've got a simple Supertest test that looks like the block below.

It's a Typescript Graphql server if that helps.

```js
// int.spec.ts

import app from '../src'
import supertest from 'supertest'

describe('API integration test', () => {
  let request

  beforeAll(() => {
    request = supertest(app)
  })

  describe('first test', () => {
    it('can do a thing', async () => {
      const response = await request
        .post('/graphql')
        .send({
          query: '{ allTransactions { merchant amount id category date } }',
        })
      const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response)
      expect(Array.isArray(parsedResponse)).toBe(true)
      expect(parsedResponse.length).toEqual(2)
    })
  })
})
```

I'm running this using the command `jest` in my package.json file:

```json
"test": "jest",
...
```

When I run `npm t`, I get the following error:

```
> jest

 FAIL  test/int.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    test/int.spec.ts:6:7 - error TS7034: Variable 'request' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.

    6   let request
            ~~~~~~~
    test/int.spec.ts:14:30 - error TS7005: Variable 'request' implicitly has an 'any' type.

    14       const response = await request
                                    ~~~~~~~

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.16 s
```

I get that the Typescript compiler doesn't like that it doesn't know what request is, but I feel like I'm making a more fundamental mistake somewhere.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

Here's the correct typing for request:

```js
describe('API integration test', () => {
  let request: supertest.SuperTest<supertest.Test> // This is what I was missing!

  beforeAll(() => {
    request = supertest(app)
  })

  describe('test title', () => {
    // I'm not including the test as its not important here
  })
```